# Is there any difference between DBA (Doctor of Business Administration) and Ph.D in a Business major?And which is better for future researchers?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, career-path, business-school

What is the main difference between DBA and Ph.D in a business major in terms of course works, study, area of specialization?
How these programs relate to future career individually?
Does DBA has the same funding possibility as Ph.D in a business major?

Comment: My guess: if you want to be an academic, get a Ph.D.  If you want to be an administrator in a business, a DBA will help you.  But that's just a guess.

Comment: What @GEdgar says is definitely true. A Ph.D. in business isn't really one in 'business'. You will be part of a group like economics, marketing, finance, accounting, or such, within the business school, and do genuine research that is meant to prepare you to enter the academic job market to teach at other business schools or related departments (economics, rarely statistics, etc.). If you look at economics, say, it's the same as an economics department, just better funded, which is reflected in facultys' salary and such. There's a recent question I couldn't find on DBAs here; not academic rly.

Comment: @ gnometorule Doesn't a Ph.D student in business major more concentrate on in a single area of specialization (e.g. accounting, finance, marketing, etc.) than the whole subjects of business?

Comment: @GoodboY: yes. The situation I'm talking about is a Ph.D. at a business school. As I said, there are different groups within a b-school, and you join one. You then predominantly only do research in that area. Given the closeness of some of the disciplines (economics/finance, economics/marketing, or finance/accounting come to mind), that's not a strict rule though. Imagine it more as an economics Ph.D. It's really not business - that gets tagged on when you, later as faculty, teach to keep the MBAs entertained.

Comment: @ gnometorule Does Ph.D in economics also focus on business subjects (management, marketing, finance) as Ph.D student in business major learns about economics?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DBA vs. PhD Perception within Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/14584/2692)